# Facing error in installing RabbitMQ on windows

Tags: flask, rabbitmq, failed-installation, erlang-otp, celery-task

I am trying to install RabbitMQ but it is giving error
[image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdD1Z.png)
please help me fix it.
I'm using windows-10 64-bit

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling RabbitMQ and Erlang/OTP but nothing seems to work.
You can also suggest me any alternatives that i can use with celery other than RabbitMQ

Comment: Don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Download versions that fit's together, i.e dependency's.
Example: RabbitMQ 3.12.1 and Erlang 26.0

1. Install Erlang, and when it is done, set environment system variable (it is version dependent), using above versions it is:

ERLANG_HOME=C:\Program Files\Erlang OTP

2. Then Install RabbitMQ
   https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html
3. Enable management plugins to frontend:

https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html

```
rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
```

There are also some configuration files to setup, but start with a successful install, so you know how that works.
https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html